# Copy file before building the image in Docker

Tags: docker, influxdb

So I just need a simply thing which is copying a script whose relative path (from the working dir.) is *influxdb/init.iql* (`InfluxDB` initialization script) to the path */docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/* which is a way to initialize an `InfluxDB` database according to `InfluxDB` Docker image [doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb):

> Initialization Files
>   If the Docker image finds any files with the extensions .sh or .iql inside of the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder, it will execute them

Right now, my *docker-compose.yml* is:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:latest
    container_name: influxdb
    ports:
      - "8087:8086"
    volumes:
      - influxdb-data:/var/lib/influxdb

volumes:
  influxdb-data:
```

I need the script to be copied *before* the image gets built as if it finds the script in the specified path, it will execute it when building the image.

How can I do this? I thought about implementing a Makefile but I would rather prefer to use Docker to accomplish this if it is possible to not add an unnecessary extra piece to the project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The docker-compose file tells how to RUN an image, not how to BUILD it. These two are completely separate. Also I'm not sure what are you trying to do. If you need to initialize your container, just mount a script to the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` location inside volumes of the docker-compose file, eg. `- project_import.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/import.sh:ro`

Comment: @emix how do I put it there? I mean, if I put the file there manually then the script will be run only when building the image locally as the volume is only in my computer, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docker-compose file tells how to RUN an image, not how to BUILD it. These two are completely separate concepts. Also I'm not sure what are you trying to do. If you need to initialize your container with data, just mount a script (or an iql file) to the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` location inside volumes of the docker-compose file, eg.:

```
volumes:
  - influxdb-data:/var/lib/influxdb
  - project_import.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/import.sh:ro
```

The script(s) (or iql file(s)) will be executed when the container starts, not when the image is built. If you don't believe me check out [the entrypoint script](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdata-docker/blob/524391fae3c3e929aae2f46ca7f388701d577249/influxdb/1.5/init-influxdb.sh#L106) of the image to see how this process works.

Just remember that those scripts will get executed each time the container starts.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks for your response. I have 2 questions: 1) in your case I assume that you have a *project_import.sh* script somewhere. What would be the path of that script where Docker will look for it? 2) what does it mean that *:ro* part at the end of the line?

Comment: 1) In the [build’s context root](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) 2) [read only](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), please read the documentation.

Comment: 1) usually it’s the place where the Docker-compose.yml file is located. That can be changed though.